# Java, Reflection, getting a Method from a Class

Tags: java, reflection

I'm having some trouble using reflection in Java.  I'm attempting to save a method of a data structure but getting an error.  The error is

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cs671.eval.SerialList.add(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)`

The method, in this case, that I'm trying to get is the add method for a SerialList that takes a Comparable and an Object as its parameters.

`structType = "cs671.eval.SerialList"`, `keyType = "java.lang.Integer"`, and `valType = "java.lang.String"` are strings that were read in from a file.

```
Class dataClass = null, comparableClass = null, objectClass = null;

try{ // create data structure
    dataClass = Class.forName(structType); 
    comparableClass = Class.forName(keyType);
    objectClass = Class.forName(valType);
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e){}

java.lang.Object structObj = null;

try{ // Create a data structure object
    structObj = dataClass.newInstance();
}
catch(Exception e){}
Method m = null;
try{ // Attempt to get add method for the data structure
    m = dataClass.getMethod("add", comparableClass, objectClass); // This is where it fails
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Basically I'm trying to get the right method on the right datastructure with the correct classes that are going to get passed into that method but I don't know how to tell the getMethod method that those classes (comparableClass and objectClass) are the correct ones.

Thanks in advance!

Added: Here's the SerialList's add method signature
`public void add(java.lang.Comparable, java.lang.Object)`

Comment: What is the signature of `cs671.eval.SerialList.add`?

Comment: Have you tried running Class.getMethods and printing the name/parameter type lists?  If e.g. SerialList extends ArrayList<String>, then the Add method will actually be add(int, Object).

Comment: @Polygnome: Addes signature to post.

Comment: @Sbodd: I wrote the add method that I'm trying to get, it takes a Comparable and Object, also the SerialList doesn't extend anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are saying -

> The method, in this case, that I'm trying to get is the add method for a SerialList that takes a **Comparable** and an **Object** as its parameters.

But passing the classes - `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.String`.

---

Just a note - Only public methods are visible to `getMethod()` for non-publics you would have to use `getDeclaredMethod()` instead.

Comment: Those classes, Integer and String, are classes of Objects that will be passed into the add method later on in the code.  I retrieved them by reading in the class name, creating a class instance of them, and passing in those class instances into the getMethod.  The getMethod is expecting a Comparable and Object though.  I need to know how to use those two classes to tell the getMethod that they are correct because the Integer will be a comparable object and the String will be an Object Object.

Comment: `Comparable.class` and `Object.class`.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode those in because later on down the line a different method could be retrieved with a different signature.

Comment: And the add method is public.

Comment: The problem is that you need to know the method signature beforehand to achieve this.

Comment: Ah, so basically what I want to do is impossible and I should hardcode Comparable.class and Object.class in and move on with my life?

Comment: @Andrew_CS - it's possible, but you have to examine all methods to see which are appropriate. I don't have time to write an answer that describes the process, but you can get what you want [here](http://kdgcommons.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/kdgcommons/lang/ClassUtil.html#getBestMethod(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) (and read the source if you want to see how to do it).

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29:

> To find a matching method in a class C:  If C declares exactly one public method with the specified name and **exactly the same formal parameter types**, that is the method reflected. If more than one such method is found in C, and one of these methods has a return type that is more specific than any of the others, that method is reflected; otherwise one of the methods is chosen arbitrarily.

=> You need to pass  `java.lang.Comparable.class` & `java.lang.Object.class`

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for providing wrong answer earlier. Based on your comments it appears that you're trying to get a Method by avoiding to provide specific parameter types needed in the signature of that method.

If my understanding is correct then you should rather use `Class#getMethods()` and examine the returned `Method[]` for your method. Consider a skeleton code like this:

```
Method[] methods = dataClass.getMethods();
boolean matched = false;
// find a matching method by name
for (Method method: methods) {
   Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
   if ( "add".equals(method.getName()) && parameterTypes.length == 2 ) {
       // method is your target method 
       // however you'll need more strict checks if there can be another add method
       // in your class with 2 different parameter types
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have stated, to use `getMethod()` you need to know and use the actual declared formal parameters of the method you are attempting to retrieve.

However, if for some reason you do not know the formal parameters at compile time, then you can iterate over all of the methods from the class until you find a method that fits your parameters (or find the most specific method that fits your parameters).

There is functionality written to do this already in apache commons bean utils, specifically in [org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#invokeMethod%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29) and [MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#getMatchingAccessibleMethod%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29).

Source code for the above methods can be easily viewed online [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.6.1/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.java#MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod%28java.lang.Class,java.lang.String,java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29).